# Poisson as hidden variable fails in PyMC3

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

Following PyMC3 code fails:

```
import pymc3 as pm
with pm.Model():
    pm.Poisson("pois", 10)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, step=pm.Metropolis())
```

Any idea why? (fails also if I switch to NUTS sampler).

Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 with pm.Model():
      2     pm.Poisson("pois", 10)
----> 3     trace = pm.sample(1000, step=pm.Metropolis())

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\sampling.pyc in sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, njobs, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed)
    155         sample_func = _sample
    156 
--> 157     return sample_func(**sample_args)
    158 
    159 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\sampling.pyc in _sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, tune, progressbar, model, random_seed)
    165         sampling = tqdm(sampling, total=draws)
    166     try:
--> 167         for strace in sampling:
    168             pass
    169     except KeyboardInterrupt:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.pyc in __iter__(self)
    814 """, fp_write=getattr(self.fp, 'write', sys.stderr.write))
    815 
--> 816             for obj in iterable:
    817                 yield obj
    818                 # Update and print the progressbar.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\sampling.pyc in _iter_sample(draws, step, start, trace, chain, tune, model, random_seed)
    247         if i == tune:
    248             step = stop_tuning(step)
--> 249         point = step.step(point)
    250         strace.record(point)
    251         yield strace

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\step_methods\arraystep.pyc in step(self, point)
    140         bij = DictToArrayBijection(self.ordering, point)
    141 
--> 142         apoint = self.astep(bij.map(point))
    143         return bij.rmap(apoint)
    144 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\step_methods\metropolis.pyc in astep(self, q0)
    122             q = q0 + delta
    123 
--> 124         q_new = metrop_select(self.delta_logp(q, q0), q, q0)
    125 
    126         if q_new is q:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    869                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    870                     thunk=thunk,
--> 871                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    872             else:
    873                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.pyc in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    312         # extra long error message in that case.
    313         pass
--> 314     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    315 
    316 

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    857         t0_fn = time.time()
    858         try:
--> 859             outputs = self.fn()
    860         except Exception:
    861             if hasattr(self.fn, 'position_of_error'):

TypeError: expected type_num 9 (NPY_INT64) got 7
Apply node that caused the error: Elemwise{ge,no_inplace}(Subtensor{int64}.0, TensorConstant{0})
Toposort index: 3
Inputs types: [TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int8, scalar)]
Inputs shapes: [(), ()]
Inputs strides: [(), ()]
Inputs values: [array(10), array(0, dtype=int8)]
Outputs clients: [[MakeVector{dtype='int8'}(TensorConstant{1}, Elemwise{ge,no_inplace}.0)]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "", line 2, in 
    pm.Poisson("pois", 10)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\distribution.py", line 27, in __new__
    return model.Var(name, dist, data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\model.py", line 276, in Var
    var = FreeRV(name=name, distribution=dist, model=self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\model.py", line 504, in __init__
    self.logp_elemwiset = distribution.logp(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymc3\distributions\discrete.py", line 209, in logp
    mu >= 0, value >= 0)

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

Comment: Try step=pm.Metropolis() or step=pm.NUTS(). Which version of pymc3 are you running? release or bleeding edge from Github?

Comment: Can you also show what kind of error message are you getting? Is Theano installed and working?

Comment: PyMC3 version: '3.0.rc2' (running over Win10 Anaconda installation).
I tried both samplers - both fail.
Theano is working fine (I work with PyMC3 extensively).

Comment: @xeon added stack-trace

Comment: Just run exact your code under Ubuntu 16.10, Anaconda, Python 3.6, PyMC3 release -- no problems.

Comment: @xeon I'm running Python 2.7 - that is the issue?

Comment: Run the code on my Win10 machine with Anaconda Python 3.5 -- same result, everything works.